# Trying to run Ubuntu 20.04. LTS through virtualbox but keep getting error message

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04

I just downloaded virtualbox and decided to use Ubuntu 20.04 as its main OS but every time it gets pass the 100% loading screen it says "errors found in 2 files! you might encounter errors." I have my virtualization technology enabled and my hyper v off. I tried re-downloading a fresh iso but still nothing. Would really appreciate the help guys. Thank you!

Comment: Errors in two files I assume is the media valuation report, meaning the ISO is corrupt, or the write to your install media was also corrupt. Did you verify your ISO as being perfect?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  (the bulk of the data is in the *squashfs*, meaning data corrupt in a single file meaning upwards of 90% of the total media is invalid)  In my experience it's the write to install media most at fault, but most users of `virtualbox` use ISOs on hdd/ssd/servers not on thumb-drive/cd/dvd media..

Comment: Also note, if insufficient RAM is allocated to a VM, false checksum errors can be detected with valid ISOs. This error occurs on virtualbox with insufficient RAM and Oracle see it as user/operator error.